# Reference root location as a variable in server {} block

Tags: nginx

In my nginx server {} block I have root defined with a path. How can I later reference this path?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/foosite;

    ...

    include $root/*.ngaccess;
}
```

Unfortunately using $root doesn't work (because I haven't defined it). Does Nginx provide a way to access the root value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want the [`document_root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_document_root) variable.

Comment: Doing this: root /var/www/foosite/public/; include $document_root.ngaccess; I get the error "nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/$document_root/.ngaccess" failed (2: No such file or directory)." $document_root seems like it would be the solution, but have I typed something wrong? According to this post (and others I came across) http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=7898, variables cannot be used in include statements. Which, if true, is unfortunate.

Comment: That implies that nginx is only evaluating the `include` directive at startup, not for every request (which makes sense), so it seems that what you want to achieve is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: I ran into a problem here too: "The path value can contain variables, except $document_root and $realpath_root." http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#.24document_root